# spring boot: how to configure datasource from application properties

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I want the below code values: `DriverClassName`, `Url`, `Username`, `Password` to be read from *application.properties* file, how to do that? I am using Spring Boot, Mysql, Hibernate and Spring Rest.

**DatasourceConfig.java**

```
    //This is working fine with inline value specified as below (DriverClassName, Url,Username,Password
    @Configuration
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.nouhoun.springboot.jwt.integration.repository")
    public class DatasourceConfig {

        @Bean
        public DataSource datasource() throws PropertyVetoException {
               final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
               dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
               dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fdb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true");
               dataSource.setUsername("root");
               dataSource.setPassword("");
               return dataSource;
    }
   ....
   ....
   ....
```

Comment: Your stack-trace indicates an issue with starting tomcat. Have you included the  tomcat dependency in the pom.xml?

Comment: You can check with @EnableConfigurationProperties(JpaProperties.class) annotation and bind the property into variable
@Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
private String url; with application.yml inside resource folder.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Once you have defined data source properties in `application.properties` in `@SpringBootApplication` it will auto configure your `datasource`, so you can remove `DataSource configuration`. But still if you want to customize your data source configuration then below should work as `Environment` should give you access of properties:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value= {"classpath:application.properties"})
public class DatasourceConfig {

    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public DataSource datasource() throws PropertyVetoException {
        final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

Or if you don't want to access properties via `Environment`, you can access by `@Value`

```
  @Value("${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}")
    private String driverName;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String userName;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    public DataSource datasource() throws PropertyVetoException {
        final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverName);
        dataSource.setUrl(url);
        dataSource.setUsername(userName);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        return dataSource;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you forget to add dependency in you pom.xml or build.gradle or your build dont have that dependency if you already added (run **mvn clean install**)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Please add and try again